# Facebook different uid, id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a web application. I am using the Devise gem and I have one controller that extends `Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController`. I use `request.env["omniauth.auth"]` to authorize user. Everything was fine during the last year up to now. At the moment I have `uid` column of the user in my database.

Now, I am building a mobile application and when I authenticate my user, I send the token to the server and I want to validate if the user has been persisted in my database. If the user has not been persisted, I should create a new account (add row in users table) and return data.

```
client = OAuth2::Client.new(
  ENV[Rails.application.config.fb_app[:id]],
  ENV[Rails.application.config.fb_app[:secret]],
  site: 'https://graph.facebook.com')
token = OAuth2::AccessToken.new(client, fb_token)
user_data = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(token.get('/me').body)
user = User.find_by(uid: user_data['id'])
```

The problem is that returned `id` is different from the my `uid` in the database. I saw that Facebook return different id-s for different FB applications but I have only one application.

Any idea how should I handle this problem?

P.S. When I get my user data from here:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=xxx
```

The id is different from my UID in the database.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you are using the same app id in both cases? And that for your `https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=xxx` call, that access token is also for the same app?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that both ids are same.

Comment: Debug the access tokens here, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/, and see what user ids it says the tokens belong to – do those match? Also, are you sure you are _handling_ ids correctly? They should be handled as text values, _not_ as integers. If you do the latter, problems with integer overflow can easily occur. (And Facebook already warns that ids might contain other characters than just digits in the future.)

Comment: The id is the same as the token from OAuth::AccessToken. I tried with Koala and it returns the same id. The problem is that when I sign up with the same user, my `uid` is still different. I use same fb app for everything.

Comment: Has the original UID been collected before April 30th 2014? It might well be the case that you migrated to v2.0 and now you get app-scoped IDs for this user. If you feel this is not the case, it would be best to file a bug report with all details you have at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs